# How to set square edged line api windows

Tags: c++, c, api, line, square

I'm using api on windows (not gdi), and i would like to know how to do square edged line.

```
MoveToEx(hdc, x1, y1, NULL);
LineTo(hdc, x2, y2);
```

My current line output :

[image: Current output]

I want this line :

[image: Desired output]

thanks, have code

Comment: what does a "square edged line" mean?

Comment: @bkVnet I think that it means the line ends are are not capped (like with a semicircle), but instead boxy.

Comment: Why does this say "not gdi" followed by an example of calls to two GDI APIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the pen style used to draw your line, specifically `PS_ENDCAP_SQUARE` and select that pen into the device context, read the documentation for [CPen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykez8tds.aspx):

```
 LOGBRUSH logBrush;//you need to use LOGBRUSH structure to specifiy brush attributes of the pen when the pen has PS_GEOMETRIC style
 logBrush.lbStyle = BS_SOLID;
 logBrush.lbColor = RGB(255,0,0);
 CPen pen( PS_GEOMETRIC |  PS_ENDCAP_SQUARE,10,&logBrush);//creates a pen with a square end caps and width of 10 pixels

 SelectObject(hdc,pen.GetSafeHandle());//select the above pen into the device context
 MoveToEx(hdc,x1,y1,NULL);
 LineTo(hdc,x2,y2);
```

Answer (score -1):

That work ! thanks !
See the following code :

```html
         LOGBRUSH logBrush;
         logBrush.lbStyle = BS_SOLID;
         logBrush.lbColor = RGB(R,G,B);
         HPEN border = ExtCreatePen(PS_GEOMETRIC | PS_ENDCAP_SQUARE | PS_SOLID | PS_JOIN_MITER, size_, &logBrush, 0, nullptr);

         SelectObject(hdc, border);
         MoveToEx(hdc, x1, y1, nullptr);
         LineTo(hdc, x2, y2);

         DeleteObject(border);
```